# Store and retrieve a long string[] for select field in reactive form

Tags: angular

Let's say you have a basic reactive form with a select field like this:

```
/* .ts */
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  hero: ['', Validators.required]
});


/* .html */
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">My hero</label>
  <div class="control">
    <div class="select">
      <select formControlName="hero">
        <option *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [value]="hero">{{ hero }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And suppose that `heroes` is an array with 100-150 entries used multiple times in your app that you don't want to store in your database.
I need to reuse `heroes` in other forms not related and in components also not related (no parent-child components).

**How do you store and retrieve your heroes?**

For now, I have a `data.ts` with all my entries that I retrieve in my component `heroes = heroes;`

Comment: Hmm.. Do you mean you wanna reuse that heroes array in other components?

Comment: And are the components related? Are they parent-child components?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to extract this array to a `service` which you can inject to every `component` you want to use.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroesService {

  heroes = [];

  constructor(){
    // you can request, or set your common array here
    this.heroes = ........;
  }  
}
```

That way, you can request the array upon initiating the service, and every component can use the same service.

```
@Component({
  selector: ....
})
export class ExampleComponent{

  constructor(private _hs: HeroesService){
    // from this point, you can access the array as _hs.heroes;
  }
}
```

(Don't forget to add the service to the `app.module` Providers) To see how to exaclty implement this, [check out the tutorial.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Answer (score 1):

If you come from a React-Redux background, you may consider implementing the Flux architecture within your application, by using [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/). It allows you to control data flow through the use of reducers/selectors. However, I would only recommend doing so if you have a more complex state management requirement, as implementing NgRX/Redux can be an overkill in small Angular projects. Othewise, the answer provided by @ForestG is more than sufficient.

Comment: Read this for the full list of ways to pass data around: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service